# Which web server to select to reconfigure phpMyAdmin automatically?

Tags: raspbian, web-server, php, apache-httpd

I am trying to install `PhpMyAdmin` with `Nginx` server on Raspbian jessie. Both `mySQL` and `Nginx` is already installed.

When installing PhpMyAdmin, it says to choose the web server. It is showing only two options `apache2` and `lighttpd`, not showing `Nginx`. What should I select ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to select web server. As I have installed `Nginx` server, so I leave this option blank. Simply pressed `Tab` key to move cursor on `OK`and hit `Enter` key.

[image]